# In Altium Designer how do I hide component origin markers and crosshairs in PCB view?

Tags: pcb, altium, layout

I am trying to clean up the view in PCB, it is cluttered with unnecessary noise, including component origins and these crosshair structures that serve no purpose for me while placing or routing. They obscure features of the components like the ref des.

[image]

[Here](https://www.altium.com/documentation/altium-designer/pcb-dlg-layerconfigurationform-pnlholder-panel-right-pnl2dsimpleconfigholder-pgcsimple2dconfiguration-sheet2dsimpleboardpreferencesview-configurations?version=17.1) it says there is an option in View Configuration but there appears to be no equivalent in the help for Altium Designer 21

I cant find it in View -> Configuration on either tab.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two tabs in the View Configuration panel, ensure that you're on the **Layers and Colors** tab. Also, be sure you've expanded the different sub-sections of the panel (**Layers** and **System Colors**). The option you are looking for, "Component Reference Point," is in System Colors, which is indicated by the arrow below:

[image: Altium Designer 21 - View Configuration]

Comment: Thank you so much that solved my problem exactly, I also turned off 3D body reference point which helped viewability immensely. I did not notice the System Colors section before because it was collapsed. Much appreciated!